# tensorboard, no visual

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to run tensorboard. I made a simple code based off the tensorboard website. Does anyone know the solution to this? Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) 
node3 = tf.add(node1, node2)
sess = tf.Session()
writer=tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/jenny/Desktop/file')
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

In terminal, this is what I ran

```
$ tensorboard --logdir /Users/jenny/Desktop/file
```

The outcome:

```
Starting TensorBoard 54 at http://jennys-iMac.local:6006
```

I pasted the address, (`http://jennys-iMac.local:6006`), [and a sign claiming the DNS address could not be found appeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Bi1.png)

When I tried `http://localhost:6006` according to Robcarney's suggestion, although the original problem was fixed, [there is no data shown; this occured for every one of the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL2zq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try just http://localhost:6006. I ran your script and recieved the same message as output, but the initial address didn't work and this one did.

EDIT: You'll also need to flush the data and close the file writer, with `writer.flush()` and `writer.close()`, in order for all the relevant graphs/events/etc. to be written to disk in your specified directory.

Comment: So I tried your link. It doesn't show the error anymore, however, no visual is shown

Comment: like there's no graph or anything @robcarney

Comment: Try adding wirter.flush() and writer.close() on to the end of your script. The graph should be in the Graphs tab on the page (not Scalars, where it will initially take you by default)

Answer (score 0):

let's try this, you didn't declare this statement **tf.summary.merge_all()**

```
import tensorflow as tf

node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) 
node3 = tf.add(node1, node2)

sess = tf.Session()
writer=tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/jenny/Desktop/file')
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

tf.summary.scalar('node3', node3)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

summary, result = sess.run([merged, node3])
writer.add_summary(summary)

print(result)
```